# How to render articles from spefic source and prevent too many request by accident?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make an app that shows news sources as a list and each source has a "Top headlines" link that takes the URL to "/headlines" endpoint. On that endpoint, I want to render a list of the top headlines from that specific news source.

---

App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Sources from "./components/Sources";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";
import Headlines from "./components/Headlines";
import axios from "axios";
import { Key } from "./API_Key"; // Import API key from outside the code.
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  // Initialize states
  const [sources, setSources] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [sourcesPerPage] = useState(10);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Get news sources from News API
    const fetchNews = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://newsapi.org/v2/sources?apiKey=${Key}`
      );
      setSources(res.data.sources); // Add news sources to "sources" state
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(res.data.sources.map(source => source.id));
    };

    fetchNews();
  }, []);

  const indexOfLastSource = currentPage * sourcesPerPage; // Get last source index
  const indexOfFirstSource = indexOfLastSource - sourcesPerPage; // Get first source index
  const currentSources = sources.slice(indexOfFirstSource, indexOfLastSource); // Get current sources

  // Change page
  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container-fluid bg-dark mb-0">
        <div className="container pt-3 pb-5">
          <h3>
            <Link to="/" className="badge badge-info">
              Back to sources
            </Link>
          </h3>
          <h1 className="text-primary mb-3">News from News API</h1>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={props => (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Sources sources={currentSources} loading={loading} />
                  <Pagination
                    sourcesPerPage={sourcesPerPage}
                    totalSources={sources.length}
                    paginate={paginate}
                  />
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/headlines"
              render={props => (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <Headlines sources={currentSources} loading={loading} />
                  <Pagination
                    sourcesPerPage={sourcesPerPage}
                    totalSources={sources.length}
                    paginate={paginate}
                  />
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
            />
          </Switch>

          <h3 className="mb-0">
            <a
              href="https://newsapi.org/"
              className="badge badge-info"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Powered by News API
            </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The news sources are sent as props to Sources-component to render a list of the sources. And also to Headlines-component to get access to the **source.id**

---

Sources.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Sources = ({ sources, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>; // Show text "Loading..." if loading not done.
  }

  /* Map through the sources received as props, and return them as a list */
  return (
    <ul className="list-group mb-4">
      {sources.map(source => (
        <li key={source.id} className="list-group-item itemhover">
          <h4>{source.name}</h4>
          <p>{source.description}</p>
          <Link to="/headlines" className="btn btn-success mr-5">
            Top headlines
          </Link>
          <a href={source.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {source.url}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Sources;
```

The news sources array is mapped through and the component returns a list-item for each source with a link for the top headlines.

---

Headlines.js

```js
import React from "react";

const Headlines = ({ headlines, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>; // Show text "Loading..." if loading not done.
  }

  /* Map through the headlines received as props, and return them as a list */

  return (
    <ul className="list-group mb-4">
      {headlines.map(headline => (
        <li key={headline.id} className="list-group-item itemhover">
          <h4>{headline.title}</h4>
          <p>{headline.description}</p>
          <a href={headline.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            {headline.url}
          </a>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default Headlines;
```

In the Headlines-component, I want to map through the headlines from the second call and return a list of top headlines from the specific source.

E.g If I click "Top headlines" link inside the BBC News list-item, then the "/headlines" endpoint should only show top headlines from BBC.

---

The problem is that I dont know where to place the second call for the headlines. I tried to put it in the Headlines-component and then use the source.id which comes as a prop in the new call (putting it in the template string as a variable), but this resulted in an endless wave of http requests which froze my browser for a while and after I managed to stop the code from running, the News API had blocked me with a timeout (Error 429 for too many requests).

---

## The idea in a nutshell:

- First page shows a list of sources, each of the list-items has a link to top headlines.
- After clicking the link, the URL moves to "/headlines" where the page renders top headlines for the specific source.

---

Can anyone tell me if I am missing just a small piece of the puzzle or do I need to make major re-write to the rendering hierarchy?

Naturally I wont give my API Key here, so you can't unfortunately test this if you don't have a key from News API.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/KariNarhi/NewsAPI-exercise)

---

EDIT: Now that I think about it, can I send the **source.id** as a prop via the Link to Headlines-component?

I've seen something like this:

```js
<Link to={{ pathname: '/headlines', source: { sourceID: source.id } }}>Top headlines</Link>
```

But how do I access this in the Headline-component?

Since I'm using function components, **this.props.location.source** wont work.

Is there some Hook for this or something?

---

UPDATE:
I added this to Headline-component:

```js
const { source } = useParams();
```

But now I get an error:

> React Hook "useParams" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?

Comment: to access ```source``` use ```useParams()``` from react router ```const { source} = useParams();```

Comment: @JuniusL. I added that but I now get an error.

Comment: please see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation

Comment: @JuniusL. OK, managed to find a way with URLSearchParams

Comment: "Since I'm using function components, this.props.location.source wont work." The fact that you are using function components shouldn't matter. Props are still passed and accessed the same way. If you don't see `this.props.location`, then you aren't using react-router correctly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice as far as I know, `this` does not work inside function components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I managed to solve this with these:

Sources.js

```js
<Link
     to={{ pathname: `/headlines/?source=${source.id}`, source: { sourceID: source.id }}}
     className="btn btn-success mr-5"
>
 Top headlines
</Link>
```

Headlines.js

```js
// Get source.id (passed in Sources.js component) parameter from URL
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const source = urlParams.get("source");
```